# Blazor cascading parameter problem in custom input that inherits from InputBase

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

So I am building a component library in blazor and I am adding support for the input components to have Blazor built in validation.

```
@inherits WindyInputTextBase;

@if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Label))
{
    <label for="@Id" class="block text-sm font-medium">@Label</label>
}

<input class="mt-3 p-2 focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:ring-primary-light focus:border-primary block w-full shadow-sm sm:text-sm border border-gray-300 rounded-md @CssClass" id="@Id" name="@Id" @bind="@CurrentValue" />
<!--Div is empty when validation is not done.-->
<div class="text-danger text-sm mb-3">
    <ValidationMessage For="@ValidationFor" />
</div>
```

The base class for the input component:

```
public class WindyInputTextBase : WindyInputBase<string>
{
    protected override bool TryParseValueFromString(string? value, [MaybeNullWhen(false)] out string result, [NotNullWhen(false)] out string? validationErrorMessage)
    {
        result = value is null ? string.Empty : value;
        validationErrorMessage = null;
        return true;
    }
}
```

And the base class of that one:

```
public abstract class WindyInputBase<T> : InputBase<T>
{
    [Parameter]
    public string? Label { get; set; }
    
    [Parameter]
    public Expression<Func<T>>? ValidationFor { get; set; }
}
```

The component (and others using the same base) work fine, but I get this error when using them outside an EditForm component:

> Unhandled exception rendering component: WindyUI.Form.EditForm.WindyInputText requires a cascading parameter of type EditContext. For example, you can use WindyUI.Form.EditForm.WindyInputText inside an EditForm.
> System.InvalidOperationException: WindyUI.Form.EditForm.WindyInputText requires a cascading parameter of type EditContext. For example, you can use WindyUI.Form.EditForm.WindyInputText inside an EditForm.

This is fine and expected, but forces me to write two sets of Input components, one that has validation and one that doesn't. I know MudBlazor does what I am looking to do, but I don't know how they do it exactly and their source code isn't all to clear for me since there is no inheritance from InputBase.

Is there a way to create a component with blazor built-in validation that can be used both inside and outside an EditForm component? Of course, this means that no built in validation is fine when not usig the components inside an EditForm.

Thanks,

Comment: Faced with the same issue, I started from here ...
https://chrissainty.com/creating-bespoke-input-components-for-blazor-from-scratch/

Comment: Thanks, Chris Sainty is indeed an amazing source.

Answer (score 0):

When validation is not needed, do not set the lambda on the component where it is used. Then create a null guard on the component itself that renders the validation message part only when the validation lambda is not null. This way it can be used without EditContext but of course will lack the built in validation as you said.